# Game Center Turn-based game

Tags: ios, game-center

Is it possible to use the GameKit framework to pass matchdata to the other player without actually ending the turn of the current player?

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to this, for iOS 7 at least, is to use the GKTurnBasedExchanges. You can send data, exchanges, replies to players even though it isn't the players turn.

I don't think there is a way to pass data to another player, then get a response back without the exchanges.

There is a way to pass data once by using saveCurrentTurnWithMatchData:completionHandler:, but the players who receive the match data won't be able to reply.